# Vagrant: Forwarded Ports doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, networking, vagrant, virtual-machine

I have a spring application which is compileable/runs on vagrant and listens to `localhost:8080` (inside vagrant).

This is my **Vagrantfile**:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 9000, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
end
```

Now I want to access my spring-application from the host machine via `localhost:9000`.

Anyway the `forwarded_port` line doesn't work and I really have no idea why?

What do I have to change in my **Vagrantfile**?

***SOLUTION:***

With the `Vagrantfile` below it works for me.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.destroy_unused_network_interfaces = true
        v.memory = 2048
        v.cpus = 4
end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because the app is listening on `localhost`.

Make the app listen on a regular interface. You might also need to add `guest_ip` if it's not the Vagrant interface.

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, guest_ip: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", host: 9000, host_ip: "127.0.0.1
```

Comment: can you be more specific? .. I am totally new to all this pseudo-server stuff

Comment: I can't be more specific, because you are not. Localhost is, as its name suggests, for local connections only.

Comment: so I have to make the spring-app listening to the `guest_ip`?

Comment: Maybe, depending on your understanding. In a common language: you need to bind it to a regular network interface, not localhost.

Comment: sorry, but what regular interface? can you give an example?

Comment: try `guest_ip: "127.0.0.1"`

Answer (score 0):

If your spring app running in the VM is indeed listening to its local port 8080, and you want to access that app as http://localhost:9000/ from your host machine, then the line in your Vagrantfile should be:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 9000
```

i.e. you have a typo specifying port 80 on the guest rather than 8080.

You probably don't need to specify any other parameters such as host_ip or guest_ip.

Comment: i found a solution and added it to my question .. thx for your effort